# Use filebeat or logstash to open gzip files

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-forwarder

I might be asking for too much here and I think it's just not implemented yet but I have ELK stack setup similar (almost identical) to how this tutorial does it:
(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04)
So basically, I have filebeat setup on a client computer, and it sends all the log files in a folder to logstash on the server computer.

What I want to do is be able to have gzip files (with text files in them) and text files a directory, and be able to send them all over to logstash with filebeat. So I need filebeat to send a unziped file, or logstash to be able to look in the gzip file and get the text file inside it.
I looked around the web and this doesn't seem to be implemented yet, but most of what I found was with log forwarder and logstash rather then filebeat, so I'm just hoping maybe there is a way with filebeat.

I might just be being overly hopeful here. If you don't know a method to do this then I'd like to know too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is currently not possible with filebeat. An issue with this feature request was opened here: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/637

A potential temporary workaround can be found here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/backfilling-old-logs-with-filebeat/38428